# How to check correct Crawled property for a list column

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-search-web-part, crawled-property

I have a couple of list columns such as `Status`, `DeptName` in my List. But when I am looking for crawled property associated to these columns in **Search Schema**, I see a list of so many crawled properties with similar names. Such as :

- ows_Status0
- ows_Status3
- ows__Status
- ows_status
- ows_q_CHCS_Status0
- ows_q_CHCM_Status0
- ows_q_CHCS_Status
- ows_q_CHCS__Status
- ows_q_TEXT_Status

I am bit confused with which one of the above to choose to map for a managed property

So for a List Column : `Status` what should be the crawled property name?

Comment: Is it your custom column or SharePoint's built in column you have used?

Comment: Its a custom column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually after full crawl , it turns out to be `ows_status` for `Status` column. 
For all the other list columns, the the crawled property with naming convention like **ows_InternalColumnName** are giving correct values for the respective columns wherease the crawled property with naming conventions like **ows_q_FourLetterCode_InternalColumnName** didn't worked for me.

Another thing I noticed that the crawled property name may be case insensetive sometimes. 
e.g. for Internal Column Name `Status` the crawled property name was `ows_status` wherease for other column `Requestor` it is `ows_Requestor`

Answer (score 11):

1. First of all if it is a custom column, you need to find what is the internal name of that column. Go to List Settings --> Click on Column name and see what is the name in the URL (Field="Fieldname").
2. What is the type of the column? **The crawled property naming convention is dependent on the type of the column**. From the column name **Status** i assume it as a  Choice field type. So for choice field type the naming of the crawled property would be : **ows_q_CHCS_ColumnInternalName** or **ows_q_CHCM_ColumnInternalName** (for multiselect choice).

Bonus: [See the naming conventions for crawled and managed properties](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/technical-reference/automatically-created-managed-properties-in-sharepoint)

Comment: Thanks. I have a crawled property named as `ows_q_CHCS_Status` which is mapped to a Managed Property `StatusOWSCHCS`. But when I use it in search result - Property Mapping, no values are displayed in search result for this property wherease the list column `Status` contains values in each item. What might be the problem ?

Comment: Is crawling in place.Make sure a full/incremental crawl is done or continuous crawl is enabled? Also make sure the Managed property has Retrievable attribute checked

Comment: Yes. the Managed Property has Retrievable attribute checked. Acutally this managed property is mapped to two crawled properties `ows_q_CHCS_Status` and `ows_q_CHCS__Status`. Is this the problem?

Comment: No when a managed property is mapped to more than one crawled property, the order of mapping will determine what value the managed property will hold.  ie if the first crawled property is null/empty, then it will take the seconf property value and so on

Answer (score 3):

A well explanatory [MSDN Article](http://blogs.technet.com/b/tothesharepoint/archive/2013/03/06/from-site-column-to-managed-property-what-s-up-with-that.aspx) to get idea from site column to Managed Property.

Assuming that it would be a choice column.

The name of this property is generated by removing spaces from the site column name, and adding a prefix. The prefix that is added varies depending on the site column type.

As it is choice column, the prefix would be:

**ows_q_< four letter code >_**

Answer (score 3):

OK, this post is old but I would like to give my answer. 
Based on your input above here it is how you should look at it.

You have two types of columns, `1) Site columns` and `2) list columns`.
In your case you have created a list column, like "Status". When the columns are created, SharePoint creates crawled properties as follows:

**Site columns**
e.g.: I create a site column called `FullName` which is of type `single line`.
SharePoint will create a crawled property as such:

```
ows_q_TEXT_FullName
```

So anything starting with `ows_q_<4 Letters>_` indicates that it is a site column.

**List columns:**
If you create a column as list level, SharePoint uses this format: `ows_<Column name>`

In your case above it will be `ows_Status`.

To distinguish between site columns and list columns simply check if the crawled property starts with `ows_q_<4 Letters of you column type>_` is a site column otherwise `ows_<your Internal field name>` is your list column.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Ive run into this many times, so what i do to overcome this is to initially name the field with an identifiable trait.

Example:
List/Solution Name: Deal Finder

Column Name: Store

Initial Field Naming: df_Store

Then, i would rename the field to just "Store"

By doing this, you are setting the internal name of the field to df_Store, which is then picked up by the search service and will name the crawled property ows_df_Store

Hope this helps