# Sharepoint Online Document Library 5000 view threshold

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, limitations

i just need some clarification regarding the Document Library size as well as the 5000 view limit threshold. I am on Sharepoint Online by the way

1. Every Document Library created, site or sub-site, can hold up to 30 million items
2. There's is a view limit threshold of 5000 items. Can avoid that by creating a filtered view which gives me less data eg group by year?
3. If i filter view by year, is the only way to find a record via the Search this site search bar instead of the Find a file search bar if i don't know what year the record is categorized in?

To be honest i am quite shocked and annoyed by this limitation. I understand the back-end processing power needed however its just not great

How do you guys deals with a Document Library with more than 5000 items? 30 million items in the library with a 5000 view limit

Comment: You use paging when getting them. `Paged=TRUE&p_ID=14000` for example

Comment: hi @NicholasDiPiazza, can you be more specific please?

Answer (score 1):

In theory, creating filtered views will work. However, for myself, this did not work as expect and cannot remove the threshold warning.

For avoiding the list view threshold, you can go to library settings >  Indexed columns(under Columns section) to create new indexes for your columns. Check below article about how to Add an index to a SharePoint column:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-an-index-to-a-sharepoint-column-f3f00554-b7dc-44d1-a2ed-d477eac463b0

Note: You need to created indices for each column.

Comment: The important point is that you should use Indexed columns in your filtered views; if you create indexes but do not filter on those columns you will not get the benefit.

Answer (score 0):

As per me i organize the Document Library in a Folder Structure like Year and months. regarding the search issue if you index specific column of the document Library still you will be able to perform the search in Search bar. we can't Increase this 5000 threshold limit in Sharepoint online at least in Server we have option to do.Actually this limit has been put on SQL database where actually List and Library data is stored.MS does not want SQL to be in deadlock situation serving large query for one user and consume all the resources.

Here is the MS link you already would have gone through 
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/manage-large-lists-and-libraries-in-sharepoint-b8588dae-9387-48c2-9248-c24122f07c59

Only thing we can make work around like use Folders, Index columns, Views but we cant change this limit put by MS.

Comment: hi @vinit kumar, would sorting the views like what you have done negate the 5000 view limit threshold? also, i have a column called customer number that is indexed. I created a view called 2017 which is filtered to only show records from anything 2017. Based on what you mentioned regarding the search bar, i should still be able to find a 2018 customer when in 2017 view? there are 2 search bars on the Sharepoint site, are you referring to the "Find a file" or  "Search this site"?

Comment: if i were to create a view, or even change and rename the default All List view to show data from the past 6 months ([TODAY]-180), would i still see the exceeded 5000 limit in the library settings page?

Comment: @Tommy, in Library settings page it will always show the threshold 500 limit is reached. but still you can add delete update into the list.its just warning.you have to define and structure your items such a way that no folder or View contains 5000 items. you have to follow the best practice only. regarding your search query search work for whole List items you cant apply a search on specific Views

Comment: Hi @vinit kumar, out out curiosity, lets say if i sort all my document into folders by year, and as an example lets say folder 2015 has 6000 documents and folder 2017 and 8000 documents, will that be an issue? since the main default view would only be showing the folders? i would assume that users will still be able to find the document(s) they want via the Find a file search bar

Answer (score 0):

The 5000 item limit is not that onerous if you leverage Search effectively. All of your list items can be indexed (meaning the full text of their properties is stored somewhere outside the SQL database), and there is no real need for you to ever see them all at once, anyway.

I would suggest planning ahead and designing your Lists/Libraries to be optimized for search, e.g. by using Site Columns and custom Content Types, indexing important columns, and using managed metadata for columns that express a hierarchy of information (e.g. product families, component trees, etc.). Then, you can create a custom page for Searching those Lists or [add a search vertical to the main Search Center](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/search/how-to-add-a-custom-search-vertical-to-your-search-results-page) that makes it easier to find things without necessarily knowing what you're looking for.

Use [Content Search Web Parts](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/configure-a-content-search-web-part-in-sharepoint-0dc16de1-dbe4-462b-babb-bf8338c36c9a) and create [Custom Refiners](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/search/how-to-add-refiners-to-your-search-results-page) so that you can drill down on results by keywords or tags. I wrote a detailed post about this [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/252047/44731).

Custom Display Templates are also beneficial where you want to customize what information is exposed by your list items in the Search Results. (However, I am not totally sure this is possible in SharePoint Online; you need access to the `_catalog/masterpage/Display Templates` directory.) ([Source](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/sharepoint-design-manager-display-templates))

Site Columns are valuable because they automatically get indexed and mapped to crawled properties in the Search Schema. ([Source](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/manage-search-schema#about-the-search-schema))

Custom Content Types are useful because you can use them to easily restrict your search results to a certain type or combination of types, making it simple to filter out all other kinds of documents and list items. ([See Also](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/manage-result-sources))