# Sharepoint 2013 - how to create managed property and map TermTitle

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, managed-metadata, sharepoint-search

I have no idea how to do this Create a Managed Property and map the TermTitle.
Could someone assist/instruct. I do not know what needs to be set in the new Managed Property and what does not.

I am wanting to create a new term as my site is searching all MS document titles. I want it to just search SP titles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to create new managed property for Search. To do this, you will need to first add custom columns to hold the property. Then make the search service application to crawl. After the custom property is crawled, you can create a new managed property and add a mapping to your crawled custom property.

Here is an [official doc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/search/manage-the-search-schema)  and a thread which you can take as reference:[how to create custom managed properties and map for CSWP in sharepoint2013/online](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/252041/how-to-create-custom-managed-properties-and-map-for-cswp-in-sharepoint2013-onlin)

I am not sure what you mean by term title, here is some information about term sets and how to use them in a managed metadata column, just have a look at them.
[Create and manage terms in a term set](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/create-and-manage-terms)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=83N8Ht60c3Y

Answer (score 0):

Title is already a Managed Property. You can query the title only by using the syntax `Title=query` for an exact match or `Title:query` for a contains match.