# Filtering by managed property in Highlighted Contents web part

Tags: sharepoint-online, managed-metadata, managed-property, highlighted-content-web-part

I am setting up a hub site with some site collections attached to it. The site collections will share the same set of content types, site columns and have common metadata stored in the termstore. I am using a PnP xml file to set up the site columns and content types so that they will have the same IDs across the site collections.

I am now trying to use the highlighted content webpart in one of the site collections, to show documents and pages that have for instance the site column "Area" set to a specific value. So I am filtering on a managed property.
The documents and pages have had the Area column set for some weeks. The values came from the termstore.

When I search for Area in managed properties in the highlighted wp I find
`AreaOWSCHCM`, `AreaOWSCHCS`, `AreaOWSTEXT`, `owstaxIdArea` and a bunch of other area variants that seem to be somewhere else in the tenant (large company). Neither of these are returning any results.

So I read that I had to map a RefinableString to a managed property. Properties I find that I could map are: `ows_Area`, `ows_Area0`, `ows_taxId_Area`, `Area`, `ows_CHCM_Area`, etc
The ones I have tried so far do not return any results, and I have re-indexed the document library.

Is there any tool available to help locate the correct properties to use in the highlighted web part?

If I manage to get it to work with RefinableStrings, do I have to set up the same refinable strings on all the other site collections if I would like to search all the sites connected to the hub?

I am site collection admin on the hub and the sites connected to the hub, but I do not have any admin rights on the tenant level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don’t seem to find such tool for this request. But there are [patterns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/technical-reference/automatically-created-managed-properties-in-sharepoint) how the crawled properties are created and named in a SharePoint environment.
Also check out this post with explanation: [How to check correct Crawled property for a list column.](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/158199/how-to-check-correct-crawled-property-for-a-list-column)

If you map the properties at site level, then it works only at current site level. So it is better that you map the properties directly at tenant level via `SharePoint admin center > search > Manage Search Schema`. Ask the organization admins to do that if you do not have enough privilege.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I recommend downloading the "SmartCAML" app from Microsoft store. You can connect to a SharePoint online site, and it will load your lists and libraries, and you can easily create a custom query. Then add that as a custom query to your highlighted content web part. When adding to web part from SmartCAML, you need to add view tag around the content seen in below support article.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/use-the-highlighted-content-web-part-e34199b0-ff1a-47fb-8f4d-dbcaed329efd

- see custom query section, use SmartCAML app